# Bug in breeze routine: protoFn.startTracking

Tags: breeze

Just found a minor bug in the following breeze routine: protoFn.startTracking

I'm not surprised that you haven't seen it before as it is in an exception:

```
prop.Name
```

should have been

```
propName or prop.name
```

Here is the rest of the routine so you can hopefully locate it.

```
// entity is either an entity or a complexObject
protoFn.startTracking = function (entity, proto) {
// can't touch the normal property sets within this method - access the backingStore directly instead.
var bs = movePropsToBackingStore(entity);
          console.log(' ', entity, ' ', proto);

// assign default values to the entity
var stype = entity.entityType || entity.complexType;
stype.getProperties().forEach(function (prop) {
          console.log(' ', entity, ' ', prop);

  var propName = prop.name;
  var val = entity[propName];
  console.log(' ', propName, ' ', val);

  if (prop.isDataProperty) {
    if (prop.isComplexProperty) {
      if (prop.isScalar) {
        val = prop.dataType._createInstanceCore(entity, prop);
      } else {
        val = breeze.makeComplexArray([], entity, prop);
      }
    } else if (!prop.isScalar) {
      val = breeze.makePrimitiveArray([], entity, prop);
    } else if (val === undefined) {
      val = prop.defaultValue;
    }

  } else if (prop.isNavigationProperty) {
    if (val !== undefined) {
      throw new Error("Cannot assign a navigation property in an entity ctor.: " + prop.Name);
    }
```

Best Niels

Comment: Thanks, I'll update it.

Comment: Hi Steve, many thanks!